# How to extract text from <span> nested in <li> which is nested in <ul> using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanna extract **Here’s what’s new** section's items from [this page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=G54HPVAW86CHYHKS), starting with *In the coming weeks* and ending with *general enhancements*.

Inspecting the code I see the `<span`> is nested under`<li>` which is then nested under `<ul id="GUID-8B03C49D-3A98-45F1-9128-392E55823F61__UL_E0490B159DE04E22AD519CE2E7D7A35B">`. I tried to extract it with Python 3 and `BeautifulSoup` for the last few days but to no avail. I'm pasting code I tried below.

Would somebody be so kind to guide me in the right direction?

1#

```
from urllib.request import urlopen # open URLs 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # BS

import sys # sys.exit() 

page_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=G54HPVAW86CHYHKS'

try: 
    page = urlopen(page_url)
except: 
    sys.exit("No internet connection. Program exiting...")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

try: 
    for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'id': 'GUID-8B03C49D-3A98-45F1-9128-392E55823F61__UL_E0490B159DE04E22AD519CE2E7D7A35B'}):
        print(ultag.text)
        for spantag in ultag.find_all('span'):
            print(spantag)
except:
    print("Couldn't get What's new :(")
```

2#

```
from urllib.request import urlopen # open URLs 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # BS

import sys # sys.exit() 

page_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=G54HPVAW86CHYHKS'

try: 
    page = urlopen(page_url)
except: 
    sys.exit("No internet connection. Program exiting...")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

uls = []
for ul in uls:
    for ul in soup.findAll('ul', {'id': 'GUID-8B03C49D-3A98-45F1-9128-392E55823F61__UL_E0490B159DE04E22AD519CE2E7D7A35B'}):
        if soup.find('ul'):
            break
        uls.append(ul)
    print(uls)
    for li in uls:
        print(li.text)
```

Ideally code should return:

*In the coming weeks, you will be able to read items that you own with a single click from the ‘Before You Go’ dialog.*

*Performance improvements, bug fixes, and other general enhancements.*

But both give me nothing. It looks like it can't find `ul` with that ID but if you `print(soup)` everything looks good:

```
<ul id="GUID-8B03C49D-3A98-45F1-9128-392E55823F61__UL_E0490B159DE04E22AD519CE2E7D7A35B">
<li>
<span class="a-list-item"><span><strong>Read Now</strong></span>: In the coming weeks, you will be able to read items that you own with a single click from the �Before You Go� dialog.</span></li>

<li>
<span class="a-list-item">Performance improvements, bug fixes, and other general enhancements.<br></li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use :contains and :has to isolate

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=G54HPVAW86CHYHKS')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
text = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('p:has(strong:contains("Here’s what’s new:")), p:has(strong:contains("Here’s what’s new:")) + p + ul li')]
print(text)
```

[image]

Currently, you can also remove the `:contains`

```
text = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('p:has(strong), p:has(strong) + p + ul li')]
print(text)
```

The + is a css adjacent sibling combinator. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). Quote:

> Adjacent sibling combinator
>
> The + combinator selects adjacent siblings. This means that the second element directly follows the
>   first, and both share the same parent.
>
> Syntax: A + B
>
> Example: `h2 + p` will match all `<p> elements that directly follow an <h2>`.

Answer (score 0):

First, the page is rendered dynamically so you have to use `selenium` to get the page content correctly.

Second, you can find the `p` tag where the text *Here’s what’s new* is present and finally get the next `ul` tag.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=G54HPVAW86CHYHKS"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

page = driver.get(url)

html = soup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for p in html.find_all('p'):
    if p.text and "Here’s what’s new" in p.text:
        ul = p.find_next_sibling('ul')
        for li in ul.find_all('li'):
            print(li.text)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Read Now: In the coming weeks, you will be able to read items that you own with a single click from the ‘Before You Go’ dialog.

Performance improvements, bug fixes, and other general enhancements.
```

Comment: I'm sure your solution is ok, however I couldn't get it to work on my machine due to numerous problems with `selenium` and its drivers.